# how to get all documents starting with specific sequence

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I like to receive all documents where key is starting with "abs" for example.

The documents in the collection users have the following keys:
'abs34kl'
'abs24io'
'abi98io'

The query should return the first and the second document.

My idea was to do it with orderBy:

```
var query = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').orderBy(...)
  .startAt(_controller.text)
  .endAt(_controller.text+"\uf8ff").limit(10);
```

How can I orderBy key? Or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: I'm not clear on what this query should do.  Could you edit the question to show some sample data of documents that you intend to match with this query?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52627798/10122791)

Comment: OK, you're saying you want to query a collection for documents whose ID starts with some string.  This will be much easier if you put the document ID into a field in the document, the sort and query using that field.

Comment: @DougStevenson, yes would be a solution. But is that really necessary to do it like that?

Comment: @Augustin-R the answer at the link you provided would mean that I need to add the key to the document itself to orderBy, right?

Comment: I don't know if Cloud Firestore indexes document IDs like it does for normal document fields, so it might not be possible unless you put the data in a field.  In general, document IDs aren't used to contain data that you intend to query on.  Usually they are just used as unique strings.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot guys!