# Is it possible to filter a Firestore Recyclerview (No third-party app)?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

Actually, I make a 1st  query which returns a number of objects.

As we could with a standard recyclerView,  I would like to filter dynamically these objects with an EditText after the view is created, and update the view dynamically.

For example, if my first query returns and displays 10 objects, the user will be able to search one objet through the 10 objects by making a request with an EditText. The view will display only this object.

```
Query query = collectionRef.whereArrayContains("customerNearMe", getCurrentUser().getUid());

private void sendToAdapter(Query query) {

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Restaurant> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Restaurant>()
                .setQuery(query, Restaurant.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new RestaurantAdapter(options);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleItemDecorator(getContext()));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
```

Actually, I know how to do it with a simple RecyclerView

```
    private void filter(String text) {
        ArrayList<ExampleItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ExampleItem item : mExampleList) {
            if (item.getText1().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) {
                filteredList.add(item);
            }
        }

        mAdapter.filterList(filteredList);
    }
```

but I am a newbie with Firestore.

Comment: What do you mean through "filter"? Please provide us an example.

Comment: @AlexMamo the post is edited,  I have tried to be more Explicit. Thank you for this observation

Comment: I think **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627194/search-by-pattern-on-cloud-firestore-collection)** it will help you.

Comment: Firestore does not support client side filtering, only queries.

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks, I check this out right now

Comment: @RonTLV yes but we cannot change the query dynamically