# How to search in Firestore database?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using this way to search for users in firestore database and I think that it is inefficient way , because it give unrelated results , for example if I type 'k' it give me results does not contain 'k' at all like the image below .

```
 var query = firestore
    .collection("users")
    .where('name', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: customer)
    .get()
    .asStream();
```

[image]

any suggestion please ?!

Comment: Firestore doesn't have any native full text search feature that you are looking for. You'll have to use 3rd party service like Algolia or store an array like `["o", "om", "oma", "omar"]` so you can use `array-contains` operator. Oh and [O is greater than K](https://jsfiddle.net/7hpebd4z/) You can read more about that in [String comparison](https://javascript.info/comparison)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using the following call:

```
.where('name', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: customer)
```

It means that you are searching the database for the documents in which the "name" property holds a value that is greater than the one you are typing. In this particular case, both "Omar" and "Second Omar" are present in the result-set, since each one of them starts with a letter that is alphabetically ordered after "k". In fact, all capital letters are present in alphabetical order after the lower-case letters. Remember that the search is performed [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order).

If you are looking for a full-text search, please note that Firestore doesn't provide one. As @Dharmaraj mentioned in his comment, you should use a third-party solution. You can also find more info in my answer from the following posts:

- [Search by pattern on Cloud Firestore collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627194/search-by-pattern-on-cloud-firestore-collection/52627798)
- [Is it possible to use Algolia query in FirestoreRecyclerOptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49596610/is-it-possible-to-use-algolia-query-in-firestorerecycleroptions/49607796)