# How to compare a string column of firestore with a arraylist?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a string column in firestore document :

```
String display = "Date, Day, Weather, Battery";
```

Now I have a :

```
arraylist<String> = "Date, Weather";
```

Now i want to get all documents from firestore where display contains any item from arraylist.

Can somebody tell, how can i do it ?

Comment: There is no way in Firestore to test based on a substring like that. If you need this, considering using a full-text search solution, such as those documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52627194/search-by-pattern-on-cloud-firestore-collection/52627798) and this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) might also help.