# Flutter Firebase OrderBy() not outputting in alphabetical order

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a reddit clone in Flutter and using Cloud Firestore to store my data. I have a list of Communities that a user is following and want to show that in alphabetical order.

My current code is as follows:

```
class CommunitiesDatabase {
  // Read all
  static Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> readAllCommunities() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Communities')
        .orderBy(
          'name',
          descending: true,
        )
        .snapshots();
  }
}
```

This is outputting the following list:

battlestations
assettocorsa
UKPersonalFinance
MapPorn
LifeProTips
Formula1

If I change the `descending` option to `false` it does reverse the order, but it still isn't alphabetical.

Can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096063/cloud-firestore-case-insensitive-sorting-using-query

Answer (score 1):

Firebase OrderBy is case sensitive.

Please check this answer on how to implement case insensitive sorting:

[Cloud Firestore Case Insensitive Sorting Using Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48096063/cloud-firestore-case-insensitive-sorting-using-query)

Answer (score 0):

Results that start wilt lower case letters will always be displayed before the ones that start with a capital letter. That's not a rule that applies only in Dart but in all programming languages.

> Can anyone help me understand why?

Why? Because it's about the [List of Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters).

You can also check:

- [How to search in Firestore database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578591/how-to-search-in-firestore-database)
- [How to search Firebase text by lower case also?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49995926/how-to-search-firebase-text-by-lower-case-also)

The last one is for the Realtime Database but the same rules apply. You can save the lower case names as well.